# Social share not working on desktop

Tags: facebook, social

I currently have this code for our social share buttons. The twitter seems to work although doesn't seem to post the image but not the others. But if I do it from my mobile it does work.

```
<div class="share{if article_author} byline{/if}">
    <span class="pull-left">Share:</span> 
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fabout&amp;text={exp:url_encode}Business News: {title}{/exp:url_encode}&amp;tw_p=tweetbutton&amp;url={exp:url_encode}http://www.example.co/section/news/{url_title}{/exp:url_encode}">
        <img src="/assets/images/share_btn_twitter.jpg" alt="Share this page on Twitter" width="39" height="19">
    </a>
    <a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/section/news/{url_title}','facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436');return false;" href="#">
        <img src="/assets/images/share_btn_facebook.jpg" alt="Share this page on Facebook" width="39" height="19">
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url={exp:url_encode}http://www.example.com/section/news/{url_title}{/exp:url_encode}&title={exp:url_encode}South East Business News: {title}{/exp:url_encode}&source={exp:url_encode}http://www.example.com{/exp:url_encode}">
        <img src="/assets/images/share_btn_linkedin.jpg" alt="Share this page on Linked In" width="39" height="19">
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:window.print();">
        <img src="/assets/images/share_btn_print.jpg" alt="Print this page" width="39" height="19">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you say more about what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

This is good you have write so many URLs to share the site on social media. You can shorten all this just by using ShareThis or AddThis.

Visit below URLs:

http://www.sharethis.com/

http://www.addthis.com/

Comment: Beware though, AddThis code is a major bottleneck to page load. If performance is a concern, keep on the path you are currently on.